# what happen if i call "delele" a CCLayer object with reference count greater than 0

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I used one scene and many layers for my game.

when user go to another game screen I remove current layer from scene , delete current layer, set current layer = NULL, then create a new layer, add it to the scene

```
void UIManager::openScreen(int screenId){
   m_currentScreen = screenId;
   CCLayer *newLayer;
   if(screenId == MENU_SCREEN){
      newLayer = new MenuLayer();
   }else{
      ...
   }

   if(m_currentLayer != NULL){
      m_scene->removeChild(m_currentLayer, true);
      delete m_currentLayer;
      m_currentLayer = NULL;
   }

   m_scene->addChild(newLayer);
   m_currentLayer = newLayer;
}
```

On some layers, i call some CCHttpRequest with callback:

```
setResponseCallback(CCObject* pTarget, SEL_CallFuncND pSelector)
```

And i use "this" to pass to "pTarget", it means first parameter for this callback is my layer which defined a SEL_CallFuncND selector.

The problem is when user switch between screens(layers) to quick, but some slow CCHttpRequest still not completed, and the response callback will be called after UIManager delete the layer then my game crash :(. I don't want to lock the screen and force use wait the http request complete. User should can abort loading a screen and switch to the next screen they want.

1. So should i call "delete m_currentLayer" instead of m_currentLayer->release()?
   As i know, release will decrease the reference count, i just want to make sure "noone" use the m_currentLayer rather than m_scene so i used "delete". But i'm not sure it is correct way.
2. If i use release function in this case, i worry some places in code use the layer and increase the retain count of the layer, is this can make a leak memory issue?
3. if m_currentLayer->retainCount() = 4 and i call "delete m_currentLayer", then what will happen with m_currentLayer?

I'm confusing with these issues, please someone give me an advide.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should not delete your nodes manually. It can cause a bunch of errors. Reference
   counting convention is to call `retain` when you need to be sure that object still exists and call `release` when you do not need this object.
2. Use `retain` and `release` only inside object, that really needs other object to exist. In any other case you can use assign property(do not retain object and check it is not `NULL`) before doing something with it. If some object(let's call it `a`), that is not yours(`CCNode`, for example) retains the other object(let's call it `b`), deleting `b` manually can cause bad access error, because `a` will be sure that `b` still exists. And can call something like `b->doSmth()`
3. Your `m_currentLayer` will be deleted, but it can cause errors because retain count 4 means that 4 objects can cause bad access error described above.

Comment: thanks @Morion! i got something useful from your answer. I'm wondering if the layer is used by callback function, it will be auto-retain? and after the callback was executed completely, it will be auto-release?

Comment: if this is cocos2d callback, that requires CCObject, most likely it will retain/release object automatically, because, as far as I remember, the only functionality of CCObject is retaincount-like system implementation.